# Disable css in test environment for Rspec

Tags: capybara-webkit, rspec3, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm using rails 4 and rspec with capybara for testing.
I want to disable css in my test environment. How can I do that? Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way - skip CSS files loading in your /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb for test env.:

```
<% unless Rails.env.test? %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara allows you to blacklist specific URLs from being loaded. You can utilize this feature to block the loading of your CSS files.  For example if your CSS is loaded from /assets/application.css:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    page.driver.browser.url_blacklist = [
      "http://127.0.0.1:#{page.server.port}/assets/application.css"
    ]
  end
end
```

You can confirm what assets are getting loaded by turning on Capybara's debugging.  To enable debugging simply set the driver to `:webkit_debug` instead of `:webkit`

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit_debug
```

Comment: But I'm using poltergeist driver for capybara.

Comment: I found this http://marcgg.com/blog/2015/01/05/css-animations-failing-capybara-specs/. But not getting how to add this file to disable css in specs.

Any ideas from you for this please.